# Keyboard shortcuts in Bash shell

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I know some useful Bash shell shortcuts, and I am wondering if there are others. The ones I know:

- CTRL + W: delete until beginning of word
- CTRL + U: delete until beginning of line
- Up / Down: navigate between previous commands

What I am especially curious are the following:

- deleting until first "/" symbol or until the point CTRL + Left would go back
- Searching in previous posts

And any other useful shortcuts, if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All this can be found in the bash [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (or type `man bash` in a shell)

Info per section:

- [Commands For Moving](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_94.html#SEC101)
- [Commands For Manipulating The History](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_95.html#SEC102)
- [Commands For Changing Text](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_96.html#SEC103)
- [Killing And Yanking](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_97.html#SEC104)

[and some more](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_93.html)

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcuts available to you depend on whether you're using bash in emacs mode (the default) or in vi mode. You can find out which mode you're using by executing

```
set -o
```

Look in the resulting list for the line beginning "vi" and see if it is "on" or "off". Then execute

```
man bash
```

and read the section on READLINE. There you will find description of at least those commands (what you call shortcuts) available in emacs mode.

Answer (score 0):

`Alt+.` to insert the last argument of the previous command.

`Ctrl+r` to search your history (though it's flaky)

History expansion in general (using `!`)

Answer (score 0):

Yyou can undo tab completion with <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: Do you mean `Esc` or do you mean `Backspace` or do you mean pressing both?

Comment: That deletes the previous "word" -- which may or may not be equivalent to the characters added by tab completion.