# Undo bash autocompletion

Tags: command-line, unix, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcuts in Bash shell](https://superuser.com/questions/155373/keyboard-shortcuts-in-bash-shell)

Is there any way I can undo an auto-completion done by bash? For example:

```
$> ls first/second/t
<Presses tab>
$> ls first/second/third
<realizes it should be fourth and not third>
<presses backspace key till initial prompt is reached>
$> ls first/second/
```

Is there any way I can replace the irritating backspacing part with some cool combo which undoes the most recent auto-completion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try undo with `Ctrl + _`

also `Ctrl + W` may do what you want. It deletes last word.

Comment: It works.:) Though for every undo required the `CTRL + _` combo has to be pressed twice! Once for undoing the additional space char and the second one to *actually* undo the suggestion. Any workarounds for this? If not, I'll mark this post as the chosen one. ;-)

Comment: Try deleting last word with `Ctrl + W`

Comment: I guess there is no single command for the same (`CTRL + W` and then `CTRL + _`). Anyways, this should be enough for the time being; solved. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that you can customize such behaviors by editing `~/.inputrc`, see `man readline` for more info and `/etc/inputrc` to see the default configuration.

Comment: @cYrus: Ooh, I didn't know that; though looking at the file makes me feel that changing it would be something pretty hardcore. Skipped for the time being. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Also try `Alt + B` and `Alt + F` (moves backwards and forward). Then you can press `Ctrl + K` to delete everything from the cursor to the end of the line